# Querying if component is in a position X, Y

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have a set of boxes in a board of 15x15.

I have only one eventlistener that catch a Touch Event and once a user tap on the screen, I need to know what box is nearest to such coordinate (x, y) given by the Event.

What could be the better way to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply take the difference of x & y positions & square them. Take the minimum **d** of all.

```
dx = x1 - x2;
dy = y1 - y2;
d = dx^2 + dy^2;
```

The two x & y would be of the box & the current touch point (Use `.localX` & `.localY` properties).

Here is a sample code, which probably has all you need :

```
board.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,function(e) {

    var minVal:int = int.MAX_VALUE;     
    var minBox:Sprite = null;

    for(var i=0; i<board.numChildren; i++) {
        var box:Sprite = board.getChildAt(i);
        var d:int = Math.pow(box.x-e.localX ,2) + Math.pow(box.y-e.localY,2);  
        if(minVal > d) {minVal = d; minBox = box; }
    }

    // You have the minimum value & closest box reference here

});
```

Comment: Hi Loxxy, good job. Thanks. The question is that every object or box has an area and your formula is based on top left corner (x,y) of every box so in many situations the result can select a box even if you're in another. All the same, It's a good starting point.

Comment: NP :)... btw it depends on where (x,y) the box is initialized, I usually do it at the center point.

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought!